# How can I write this select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract some data to analyse exceptions/logs, and I'm stuck at a point.

I have a table with a column called `CallType`, and a status which can be **Success** or **Failure**. This table also has a column called `SessionId`.

I need to do this:

Select all the `SessionId`'s where all the `CallType = 'A'` are marked as **Success**, but there is at least one `CallType = 'B'` having a **Failure** for that session.

There will be a where clause to filter out some stuff.

I'm thinking something like:

```
select top 10 *
from Log nolock
where ProviderId=48  -- add more conditions here
group by SessionId
having --? what should go over here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with conditional aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
select top 10 *
from Log nolock
where ProviderId=48  -- add more conditions here
group by SessionId
having sum(case when CallType = 'A' and Status = 'Failure' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when CallType = 'B' and Status = 'Failure' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CallType = 'A' and Status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause checks for three conditions by counting the number of rows that meet each one.  If `= 0`, then no records are allowed.  If `> 0` then records are required.

- That `CallType A` has no failures.
- That `CallType B` has at least one failure.
- That at least one `CallType A` success exists.

The third condition is ambiguous -- if is not clear if you actually need `CallType A`s to be in the data, based on the question.

Comment: I think for OP's requirement, change the conditions to `sum(case when CallType = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = sum(case when CallType = 'A' and Status = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) and sum(case when CallType = 'B' and Status = 'Failure' then 1 else 0 end) > 1` is better.

Comment: @JaugarChang . . . According to the question, `status` is always either "Success" or "Failure".  So, saying that all are "Success" is equivalent to saying that none are "Failure".  Formulating the logic in terms of "Success" is fine.  I just find saying no "Failure" is more succinct.

Comment: I quite agree with you. But I think my version is just better for review and understand. And even if there will be more status added in, it still work, because it just hit the requiement, no more or less.

Comment: thanks, but for the second condition, shouldn't it be >0 instead of >1? because we should get atleast 1 failure. Am I right?

Comment: @karank . . . Yes.  That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Having clause can only operate on aggregates within the group so this isn't the correct way to go about it since you are filtering out other rows you want to check against. I'd use `EXISTS` for this e.g.

**edit**: corrected the query

```
SELECT *
FROM Log L WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ProviderId = 48
AND CallType = 'A'
AND Status = 'Success'
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Log WHERE L.SessionId = SessionId AND CallType = 'B' AND Status = 'Failure')
```

You can essentially filter out rows in the `EXISTS` part of the query using the aliased `Log` table (`aliased L`), matching all rows with the same session ID and seeing if any match the filters you required (failed with call type B)

Comment: I assumed you aliased your table as nolock rather than you wanted a NOLOCK, if you want a nolock you need to use `WITH(NOLOCK)` instead otherwise you are just aliasing the `Log` table

Comment: Not correct: "The following table hints are allowed with and without the WITH keyword: NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED, UPDLOCK... " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187373.aspx. But it's nicer to be specific to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: Ah I did not know that, thanks for the info :) - I assume you would need [] to alias as [nolock]?

Comment: It seems that you have to use WITH() if you are already aliasing the table, otherwise nolock on its own will do

Comment: @Charleh that is incorrect. If you do not have an alias on a table and put nolock without the WITH keyword the table will be aliased nolock. Using table hints without the WITH keyword has been deprecated to avoid confusion like this. Here is proof that not using the WITH keyword will result in an alias. select *
from sys.objects nolock
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = nolock.object_id

Comment: Ah, that's what I originally thought - so you are saying my original (first) comment is correct? (and Tanners is incorrect?). My original answer took this into account but I modified it to be explicit

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Log L WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  L.CallType='A' 
AND    L.[Status] = 'Success'
AND    L.ProviderId = 48
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM Log 
            WHERE L.SessionID = SessionID
             AND  CallType='B'
             AND  [Status] =  'Failure')
```